# explain how description method works in NSObject class

Tags: objective-c, nsobject

In NSObject.h header file, i have seen a method

```
+ (NSString *)description;
```

I knew that "+" sign before the method indicates that it is a class method

Here is my entire program

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface A : NSObject
@end

@implementation A
@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {

    A * aObj = [A new];
    NSLog(@"%@",[A description]);//o/p: A
    NSLog(@"%@",[aObj description]);//o/p: <A: 0x10010f5a0>
   }
   return 0;
}
```

I have used the description method with both class as well with instance of it and i got the o/p as well. why i have not received any error or warning while using a class method using an instance particularly in this case

```
[aObj description];//why this piece of code is working fine
```

Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 4):

Because `NSObject` has two methods:

```
+ (NSString *)description; // Class method 
- (NSString *)description; // Instance method
```

So when you do `[A description]` you're calling the class method (declared in [`NSObject` Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/description)), when you do `[aObj description]` you're calling the instance method (declared in [`NSObject` Protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/description)).

Comment: technically, it's the same method. The metaclass also inherits from `NSObject`.

Comment: I agree, but let's stay simple and just pretend there are two methods. For the question asked, I'm afraid it would not have been a good idea to get too deep in the details of meta-classes. That's why I'd rather stay with the two declarations, enough self-explaining to answer our friend.

Comment: I disagree that it wouldn't be good to "get too deep".  Sunil isn't the only person that's going to read the question or its answers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Zaphod, As i'm new to this.. the above two methods made me confused.. Now i got the point.. In my point of view understanding in depth gives knowledge as well confidence to the programmers ;)

Comment: @Sunil I'm glad if this is useful. And I agree, there's nothing worse than magic in the programming world... But if you think the answer is correct, you can accept the answer... ;o)